Got ClassNotFoundException while building native image with grpc-netty-shaded 1.65.1
The version of grpc-java is 1.65.1, and I'm using grpc-netty-shaded in Nacos, which is an experimental version supporting Spring Boot 3.3.1. While using native:compile, the project encountered an exception as shown below:
[ForkJoinPool-2-worker-2] ERROR io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils -- Unable to initialize BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLEngine

I believe the above error is caused by introducing a class in the project that uses BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils. BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils tries to obtain the BCSSLEngine class via reflection during its static initialization, but since I haven't used the BCSSLEngine class in my project, it leads to the ClassNotFoundException mentioned earlier.
Because I'm not very familiar with gRPC, I can't confirm where BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils is used in gRPC Netty Shaded. Therefore, I attempted to summarize all the classes related to io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty used in Nacos:
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.Channel
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext

io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ClientAuth

io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder

io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf

io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString

I also collected some grpc-netty-shaded classes needed at runtime in native image:
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AbstractReferenceCounted</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.PemPrivateKey</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.UnpooledHeapByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.UnpooledDirectByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.PooledSlicedByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.AbstractPooledDerivedByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.buffer.ByteBufAllocator</buildArg>
<buildArg>--initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.PemValue</buildArg>

I tried to resolve the ClassNotFoundException related to the BCSSLEngine class by adding some dependencies of org.bouncycastle to the project, but this introduced a new issue:
[main] ERROR io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils -- Unable to initialize BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils.
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: BCJSSE

So, I abandoned this approach of adding dependencies. I have confirmed that Nacos does not directly use any methods related to the BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils class, which supports my previous hypothesis about the problem. Can anyone familiar with gRPC provide me with some assistance? Thank you very much!

Resolved with argument --initialize-at-run-time=io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.BouncyCastleAlpnSslUtils
